# How many concurrent import activities to DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, import

In the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/optimizing_api_calls_and_data_structures_to_improve_performance_in_the_salesforce_marketing_cloud.htm) it is said:

Concurrent Imports to a Data Extension ,Normal: 1, Aggresive: 2, Extreme: 3 or more.

Does anyone know if it means that its not recommended to perform 3 or more imports in the same step of an automation or is it not recommended to perform 3 or more imports to the same DE?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never had a problem running multiple imports to separate data extensions within the same step of an Automation - I've ran 19 imports once.

What isn't advisible is to run multiple imports to the same data extension within the same step - instead you are best to separate them into multiple steps or question why you are receiving multiple files to import to the same data extension, as this wouldn't be good Architecture Design